# как передать с формы дату в контролер и получить её там? страница jsp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, дата

есть форма 
<\form:input path="date" class="formas" type="date" placeholder="${date}"/>"

мне надо вывести в контроллере System.out.println("date :" + test.getDate());

чтобы потом изменить данные Даты в БД а у меня в контроллере показывает null

делаю через hibernate и java.util.Date;

если можно наглядный пример как отправлять дату с формы и получать  в контроллере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте замаппить параметр "дата" вот таким образом:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testme" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String testMe(@RequestParam("odate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date odate) {
   //.....
}
```